# Clear directories

Tags: bash

I have list of parent folders; inside every parent folder I have sub folders and files. How can I empty the parent folders -- i.e remove all the files and sub folders and leave the parent folders empty?

```
Parent folder A
       subfolder aa
       file a
Parent folder B
       file b
       file vv
Parent folder C
       subfolder s
       subfolder n 
        file x
.
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With GNU `find`:

```
find "Parent folder A" "Parent folder B" ... -mindepth 1 -delete
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, tell `rm` to start removing under each parent folder:

```
# set dotglob to have * include files beginning with '.'
shopt -s dotglob
rm -r "Parent folder A"/* "Parent folder B"/* ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are no files in the top level directory:

```
for i in *; do (cd "$i"; rm -rf *); done
```

or

```
for i in *; do (cd "$i"; for j in *; do rm -rf "$j"; done); done
```

I prefer the latter, because it does not try to remove `*` if the directory is empty, and it can be easily modified to include only some file patterns. For anything more complicated, use `find`.

Answer (score 0):

Asuming you cwd (current working directory) is where the all the parent folders are, you could do something like this:

```
for i in *; do
    [[ -d "$i" ]] || continue
    rm -rf "$i"/*
done
```

- Loop though all directories in current folder (i.e. the parent folders)
- remove all files and folders within each subfolder

Comment: Eek. What do you think will happen with filenames containing spaces? [Don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: @muru - the spaces arent important. the value of `$IFS` is, and moreso the shell's current `-f`ilename generation settings. thomas - your thing could glob out to unintended paths.

Comment: `mkdir 'files ..'` for example

Comment: @muru - you're right... I should have seen this. I have updated the answer. Thanks for noticing.